# How to create UITableViewController as reusable module?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

I am new to iOS development. I have created two classes of `UITableViewController`. One is list of `Tasks` and second one is the list of `Notes`.

Now the problem is both of these `UITableViewController` are needed on many screens (on some screens both simultaneously). I don't want to re-write all code for `UITableView delegates and datasource` on every screen. I want to re-use both `UITableViewController` with some mechanism of inheritance or module system.

So that on every `UIViewController` where i need to display list, i just have to add a `UITableView` in nib file, sets its custom class and it should start displaying data.

Is it possible with some kind of inheritance, component or module system?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for reply, i have already created a separate UITableViewController, and have implemented all required delegate and datasource method. Now i want to use this UITableViewController on multiple screens. Tasks and Notes are complete different things. You can forget them. The problem is how to re-use a UITableViewController on multiple screens.

Answer (score 0):

Create subclass of UITableViewController add all of the required delegate methods and in .h file add:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSArray *myData;
```

All of the method set up base on that array, for example:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.myData;
}
```

When you want to use this just create object and pass your data:

```
MYTable *tableViewController = [[MYTable alloc] init];
tableViewController.myData = DATA YOU WANT TO DISPLAY;
```

It will work but you have to pass exactly the same data structure to your NSArray to handle it right in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Comment: thanks for reply. I am still confused.
I have created TaskViewController which is working good. Now i want to use it in my actual screen DashboardViewController. So how should i use TaskViewController, in DashboardViewController? If i do TaskViewController *taskVC = [[TaskViewController alloc] init];
[taskVC.tableView reloadData]; 
It doesn't work. For the time being i have hard coded the dataArray in TaskViewController.

Comment: Don't hardcode dataArray, use property I put to my post and once you create it add: taskVC.dataArray = your array to display.

Comment: Thanks Greg, data is no problem for me. It is already set in TaskViewController, you can suppose i need to display a hard coded data in all screen. Therefore i have create data within TaskViewController. So no need to set again and again in all other screens. Actually i am thinking about MVC pattern. I want to create a view controller. That i can use on any screen i want. Like a component or plugin.

Answer (score -1):

Hey mate you need to maintain two array and create a toggle button ex. a/b

if a is pressed then fetch the count of one array, if b is pressed count the array of other dictionary. And do this by maintaining a BOOL variable.

ex.
BOOL checkvalue;

```
-(UIButton *)a:(id)button
{
     checkvalue = TRUE;
     [tableview reloadData];
}
-(UIButton *)b:(id)button
{
     checkvalue = FALSE;
     [tableview reloadData];
}
```

now put the condition in the tableview counting number of rows, and cellforrowatindexpath method.
like,
// for numberOfRowsInTableview

```
if(checkvalue == TRUE)
{
return [arr1 count];
}
else
{
return [arr2 count];
}
```

and similarly for cellForRowAtIndexPath
Thanks and have a nice day.